# Node js: problem with text values read from .txt file

Tags: node.js, json, encoding, txt

I have code with next algorithm:
reading text from .txt file using built-in fs module -> writing into object -> making a json file from it -> reading this json file in other script
The problem is, that after this way of text, string from txt file does not equal string with the same text written in the same script:
'en' != gotFromTxt //gotFromTxt is 'en' as well

I tried to change encoding in all this operations to utf-16, as well as other couple of encoding values, however it did not work

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide an [example of the code and files](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce the issue and help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.